# Postgres convert string to composite array

Tags: postgresql

I have a Type with below structure.

```
create type t_attr as (id character varying(50), data character varying(100));
```

I get text value through a user-defined function. In the above type both `id` and `data` will have comma-separated values. The length of the array can vary between 1 and 100. Below is a sample text value I get as function input parameter which if converted to array should have length 2.

```
txt text := '("id1,id2,id3", "dat1,data2,dat3"), ("id4,id5,id6", "dat4,dat5,dat6")';
```

In `txt`, `'id1,'id2,id3'` is the `id` of type `t_attr[1]` and so on.

I tried as below to convert it to array, but I'm always getting either 'malformed record literal' and 'Too many columns'.

```
   arr_attr := array[txt]::t_attr[];
```

`arr_attr` should look like this after loading with sample data:

- `arr_attr[1]` should look like `("id1,id2,id3", "data1,data2,data3")`
- `arr_attr[2]` will be `("id4,id5,id6","data4,data5,data6")`

Comment: Hmm. There are unmatched quotes in your input data. What programming language is that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, can you please help on how the quotes should look like for it to work fine? Its being sent from Java code and quotes can be manipulated as required.

Comment: No, I mean the code like in your question that starts with `txt text := ` contains 9 single quotes, so I don't know what exactly you mean with that line. I don't know any programming language where such a line would be valid.

Comment: single quotes in single quotes won’t work magically without any escaping.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, edited the  txt  part. Replaced single-quotes with double-quotes for each array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty, but this should work:

```
WITH x(e) AS (
   SELECT regexp_split_to_array(
             trim(q.q, '"'),
             '", "'
          )
   FROM regexp_split_to_table(
           trim(
              '("id1,id2,id3", "dat1,data2,dat3"), ("id4,id5,id6", "dat4,dat5,dat6")',
              '()'
           ),
           '\), \('
        ) AS q
)
SELECT ROW(e[1], e[2])::t_attr FROM x;

                row                
-----------------------------------
 ("id1,id2,id3","dat1,data2,dat3")
 ("id4,id5,id6","dat4,dat5,dat6")
(2 rows)
```